# django-wysiwyg-redactor's table plugin button is not showing on the toolbar

Tags: django, wysiwyg, django-wysiwyg

I am using [django-wysiwyg-redactor](https://github.com/douglasmiranda/django-wysiwyg-redactor).
Redactor is showing and working fine, but Table plugin is not working. It's not even showing on the toolbar. That's what I have:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    text = RedactorField(redactor_options={
                             'lang': 'en',
                             'plugins': ['table']
                         })

class CreateMyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = '__all__'


{% load static %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

<script>var RedactorPlugins = {};</script>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
      {{ form.media }}
      {% crispy form %}
    </div>
```

What I am doing wrong? And how to solve this problem?

Django version is 1.8.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I screwed up!
I was using old version of redactor. In the last version this bug fixed.